# How to organise database structure to be able to search in them. Firebase and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How should I store my objects in the `IngredienData` database to be able to implement to a search with autocompletion and add from the data to them to `usersList`.

This an example of how the search autocompletion will look:

[image]

This is my data structure:

[image]

Comment: Has it helped?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

So, after the conversation in the skype:

1) You should have a dictionary in your database with:

```
 - unicId of the ingredient 
 - name of ingredient
```

like a special node with not full info (just `unicId: Name`) (for the future, when ingredient will grow for like 10 nested nodes array)

to be ready to organize quick search with autocompletion. You will autocomplete with array of `ingName` from this node values.

You need to store your list of ingredients ids in `usersList/unicId`.

So, to retrieve full info, you will get the unicId and go to `IngredientData` to get full info.

That helped.

Comment: Thank you for this response. I forgot to mention that I did do something similar to this when I try and "edit" an item as I refer to its `ref.key`. However this was done using a table cell where the data was transferred to the editViewController depending on which cell was selected, I also can "delete" by selecting that cell. My aim is to be able to recognise that ingredient by checking if it exists in the `IngredientData`. Then adding it to either my `usersList` or `recipe`. Would it be better for me to show you how I did the "edit" and "delete"?

Comment: @Chace no:) Do you want to check the IngredientData, if it contents data with specific key? Have I correctly understood you?

Comment: Yes. I simply want the `usersList` of ingredients to share same `uid` as the `recipe`'s. I thought the best practice was to have a table of Ingredient (`IngredientData`) where both `usersList` and `recipe` can add from. Sorry if I am not very clear :/

Comment: @Chace check update. But its not pretty simple to understand, what do u want actually:)

Comment: Sorry if I am not very good at explaining this. I simply just want to check if the user has the same ingredient as the ingredient inside recipe.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck on the `refToRec ` part, where would I initialize it. Also I am not sure how it is getting `ref` that's why when I run it and try to add an ingredient it says `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
`. Have you looked at how I add an ingredient?

Comment: @Chace wait, I'll come home and answer

Comment: Is there any possibility we can try a chat room in case this conversation gets long? :)

Comment: @Chace we can have a skype call if u want to. Cz I'm a bit stucked with your logic actually:(